# ngrok + Local IIS: how to expose a website

Tags: c#, iis, paypal, ngrok

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project in which I use Paypal thus I want to debug a webhook implementation.

I'm running my project with the local IIS and I followed [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/03/configure-windows-for-local-webhook-testing-using-ngrok.html) to try to expose it to the web but it's not working. I tried everything in it.

I run on Windows 10 and  IIS 10.0.14. My local IIS website runs on door 80 and 443 (SSL enabled). I had XAMPP running in the same door then I changed it to run on 81 and 442.

Can you help me? Is there anything I'm missing?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

read following article. I have used it successfully on my side.
https://vipul1989.wordpress.com/2017/06/09/using-ngrok-to-expose-your-localhost-to-web/

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tried this as well. Doesn't work for me =/

Comment: The only difference was that I was using IISExpress while keeping application running. Can you please let me know what is the error you are getting.